# win server 2003 crashed 8-(

Tags: windows-server-2003, scsi

All of a sudden Win 2003 server crashed on PowerEdge 2003. All the drives are SCSI based. I can't the access them anymore... What would be the best way to recover the files? I opened the server. There are no IDE drives on motherboard, but four 36gb SCSI.

Comment: How exactly is 'can't access anymore' ? Does it still power up?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look first if your SCSI controller is still alive. That might have been the one that has taken the nose dive. It also doesn't make sense that 4 SCSI drives would all die in one shot (and your controller is the single-point-of-failure, in this case).

In any case, make sure your power supply is delivering enough juice to power everything in your server as it might not be delivering enough current to "start up" the 4 drives.

Answer (score 0):

Run whatever diagnostics are available during the boot process, especially the SCSI controller diagnostics. Your machine may have come with a bootable CD to assist in this. If all that checks out you may want to try using a live CD to check the file system (I like BartPE for this).